# Need to calculate months between two dates in JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to count total no of months between the two dates in months and years if not just months either any php snippet or ether js or jquery.

I display the data from backend using php tags {{ $job->job_start_date }} job_start_date is for start date and {{ $job->job_expiry_date }}) job_expiry_date is for end date.

I get my output as in this format 13-Oct-2016.
I tried this thing putting the values as hidden but couldn't get it work with parsing properly while adding new Date() to them

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var sDate = $("#monthStart").val();
    var nDate = $("#monthEnd").val();

    var sd = new Date(sDate );
    var ed = new Date(nDate );
    ed.setDate(ed.getDate() - sd.getDate());
    alert(monthDiff(sd,ed));
});


function monthDiff(d1, d2) {
    var months;
    months = (d2.getFullYear() - d1.getFullYear()) * 12;
    months -= d1.getMonth() + 1;
    months += d2.getMonth();
    return months <= 0 ? 0 : months;
}
```

need a easy solution in js jquery or php.

Comment: i have created in angularjs hop it will help you. http://codepen.io/halimmln/pen/NRPBBK

Comment: It is not clear how you define the number of months. For example, is difference between 30th/Sep and 1st/Oct going to be 1 month or 0 months? In general, when working with date and time it is a good idea to use some library, like [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) just because of all the corner cases you may end-up handling.

Comment: I need to count it as 28 days

Answer (score 2):

```
function MonthDiff(date1, date2) {
    var Nomonths;
    Nomonths= (date2.getFullYear() - date1.getFullYear()) * 12;
    Nomonths-= date1.getMonth() + 1;
    Nomonths+= date2.getMonth() +1; // we should add + 1 to get correct month number
    return Nomonths <= 0 ? 0 : Nomonths;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function differenceInMonths($startDate, $endDate)
{
    $date1 = new DateTime($startDate);
    $date2 = new DateTime($endDate);

    $interval = date_diff($date1, $date2);

    return $interval->m + ($interval->y * 12) . ' months';
}
```

This way you get no. of months. Now you can calculate years if months >= 11.

Answer (score 1):

Well in this case you can take advantage of `moment.js` library.

Assuming you have `Date String` in format like "1-Sept-2016" then we need to convert it to date and then apply moment. If you already have `Date` then you can directly apply the `moment`.

**Demo :**

```js
var startDate = new Date('01-Sept-2016' );
var endDate   = new Date('30-Oct-2016' );
    
var endMoment   = moment(endDate);
var startMoment = moment(startDate);

 //[days, years, months, seconds, ...]
console.log(endMoment.diff(startMoment, 'months'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.15.1/moment.js"></script>
```

You can even specify the difference you want like `days`, `months`,`years`, `seconds` as specified above.

> Reference : http://momentjs.com/

Comment: I think your coding quite  worng. The logic is, if you put 1 oct 2016 and 30 sept 2016 it will be 2 month not 1 month.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a php solution:

```
$noMonth = 1 + (date('Y',strtotime($job->job_expiry_date)) - date('Y',strtotime($job->job_start_date))) * 12   +   (date('m',strtotime($job->job_expiry_date)) - date('m',strtotime($job->job_start_date)))
```

The first part calculates the difference in years, multiplied by 12 results the number of month:

> 1 + (date('Y',strtotime($job->job_expiry_date)) -
>   date('Y',strtotime($job->job_start_date))) * 12

The second part calculates the number of months to be added or subtracted, as if the dates were in the same year:

> (date('m',strtotime($job->job_expiry_date)) -
>   date('m',strtotime($job->job_start_date)))